# Can't get Siri to set a reminder for me to call my bank

Tags: siri, reminders

I need to confirm a change of address with a bank on January 1.  So I do my usual and ask Siri to set a reminder for me to do so.

"Hey Siri, remind me on January first to call US Bank about the address change"

Siri responds every time with:

"I don't see U Bank in your contacts.  Perhaps you meant one of these?" and then displays a bunch of contacts that start with the letter U.

This is really annoying... I use Siri all the time and almost never, ever, have even the slightest problem getting her to do whatever I need.  But this particular phrase just seems to stump her.  The text readout of what she thinks I said is perfect, but her response is not.

Incidentally Voice Dial is off, in case anyone thinks that's related.

Why is she misinterpreting this and insisting that I'm trying to call a specific contact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're using the words "to call". By default Siri is interpreting this as you wanting to call a contact, which in this case is missing.

Perhaps you could just change the words to something like:

*"Hey Siri, remind me on January first to change the address for US Bank"*

This should just create a reminder for 9am on 1st January to change the address for US bank.

Comment: Sure I can do that, but I phrase reminders to call people like this all the time and I've never been asked to pick the specific contact before.

Comment: Oh, I see. Perhaps it's because of the apparent _initials_ that Siri is behaving differently in this regard? The 'U' and 'S' may be throwing it off, i.e. In combination with the "to call" preceding it. Not sure why though.

Comment: Yeah it does seem for some reason that it is the initials. Although as I mentioned in the question the text read out displayed of what I said is perfectly correct, so the text interpreter did at least get it right… strange.